# Building a binary inside docker and mount back to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a requirement where I need to build a executable binary but inside a docker container because of the difficulty in building the binary in different environments. I have a sample `docker-compose` of what I want and trying to convert it to a Dockerfile. The docker-compose is as below.

```sh
version: "3.7"

services:
  wasm_compile_update:
    image: envoyproxy/envoy-build-ubuntu:e33c93e6d79804bf95ff80426d10bdcc9096c785
    command: |
      bash -c "bazel build //examples/wasm-cc:envoy_filter_http_wasm_updated_example.wasm \
                && cp -a bazel-bin/examples/wasm-cc/* /build"
    working_dir: /source
    volumes:
      - ../..:/source
      - ./lib:/build
```

What will be the equivalent Dockerfile for this ?? I was trying to use CMD but couldn't make it work. Any help will be appreciated since I'm on a tight deadline. Thanks

Comment: How did you try to use CMD and why didn't it work? And, just to check that you didn't forget something easy, when you built the Docker image that tried to use CMD to achieve the same functionality, did you make the other pieces of configuration from docker-compose match up with your 'docker run' invocation (eg did you mount the volumes or specify the working dir)?

Comment: No the thing is I don't know how to use docker for this kind of a scenario. Here I want to run this without building or anything.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you have time, can you help me improve it a little by telling me what I've got wrong from a detail perspective? It would be a more useful answer for other people if we could remove all of the assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dockerfile that'll have the right tools in to build your binary, but you'll still have to use docker run to do the build itself because you can't mount drives during the build process nor can you copy things out of the image during the build. However, you can do this:

A dockerfile

```
from envoyproxy/envoy-build-ubuntu:e33c93e6d79804bf95ff80426d10bdcc9096c785
workdir /examples
entrypoint ["bazel", "build"]
```

Build it like this:

```sh
docker build -t MyBuildkit .
```

And run it like this:

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
  -v $(pwd)/examples:/examples \
  -v $(pwd)/bin:/bazel-bin/examples/wasm-cc \
  MyBuildkit /examples/wasm-cc:envoy_filter_http_wasm_updated_example.wasm
```

Now, I don't know enough about the directories here to work out if that's exactly right, but the gist is there.

The first volume mount (`-v`) is there to mount your source code (which I'm assuming is `examples`) into a folder in the container (which I've also called `examples`). The final bin directory is also mounted, in the second mount, which I've mounted into a host folder called `bin` and I've assumed that the copy command you had contained the binary so that would ma to `/bazel-bin/examples/wasm-cc` in the container.

Another assumption I've made is around the command to send to the container. I've set the entrypoint to be what is presumably your compiler (`basel build`) and to that I've passed in what is presumably the name of the thing to build (`/examples/wasm-cc:envoy_filter_http_wasm_updated_example.wasm`).

Because I don't know basel at all it is entirely possible that I've got one or more of these details wrong, but the general pattern stands. Mount your `source` and your `bin`, pass the target of the build into the `entrypoint`, and build into the `bin`.